# swift2 how to print the error message in the catch

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have this custom error class:

```
enum RegistrationError :ErrorType{
    case PaymentFail
    case InformationMissed
    case UnKnown
}
```

And I define a function like this:

```
    func register(studentNationalID: Int)  throws -> Int {
    // do my business logic then:
    if studentNationalID == 100 {
        throw RegistrationError.UError(message: "this is cool")
    }

    if studentNationalID == 10 {
        throw RegistrationError.InformationMissed
    }
    return 0
}
```

I call that function like this:

```
do{
    let s = try register(100)
    print("s = \(s)")
} catch  RegistrationError.UError {
    print("It is error")
}
```

my question is how to print the error message that I have thrown when I throwed the exception?

I am on Swift2

Answer (score 2):

If you catch an error with a message, you can print the message like this:

```
do{
    let s = try register(100)
    print("s = \(s)")
} catch  RegistrationError.UError (let message){
    print("error message = \(message)") // here you will have your actual message
}
```

However even if you didn't throw any message, you still cant catch a *message*, which is the type of the error like this:

```
do{
    let s = try register(10)
    print("s = \(s)")
} catch  RegistrationError.UError (let message){
    print("error message = \(message)")
}
catch (let message ){
    print("error message = \(message)") //here the message is: InformationMissed
}
```